# This algorithm seems to be consistent with counting the real interval, what's wrong with it?

Tags: set-theory

So I've been imagining infinite sets, specifically the real numbers,

Here's the algorithm,

start at .1, then as follows, .2, ... .9, .01, .11 ... .99, .001, ... .999, etc.

Why wouldn't this generate the reals at infinity? I realize this is a countable set, it's informally an inversion of 1 ... infinity, so it's countable. Yet if you describe .1 as existing in column 1 and .99 as column 99, that would imply that if you choose a .2516 at column 1 not equal to .1, that it would show roughly in column 6152.

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Which position in this list is $1/3$?

Comment: You won't get $\pi/4$ this way.

Comment: You're missing all the reals that have a non-terminating decimal expansion, e.g., $\frac13 = 0.333...$, but also $0.123456789101112131415...$

Comment: Thank you for your examples.

Comment: Every number in this list has a finite decimal expansion , as explained in the above comments. In fact, the numbers with terminating decimal expansion , as a subset of the rational numbers , are countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have described is a [*van der Corput sequence*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Corput_sequence), which does get arbitrarily close to each real number in the interval, but the sequence doesn't contain numbers like $\frac19$ that *don't eventually terminate*. Every number in the sequence has a terminating decimal expansion.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm happy to see the reference!

Comment: This answer is absolutely right, but let me point out that we can also address this using ... Cantor's diagonal argument! Remember that the diagonal argument is **constructive**: it gives a procedure for taking a listing $F$ of reals in the unit interval and spitting out a real $\alpha_F$ not in the range of $F$. You've described such an $F$, so you can just check by hand what Cantor does to that $F$.